# How do I install plesk from downloaded file in Ubuntu

Tags: installation

Its simple really, I would like to be able to run the auto installer I have downloaded from here: http://www.parallels.com/download/plesk/10/

I downloaded **parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386** for my Ubuntu 10.4 32-bit.

I have added to folder path /plesk/parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386 but when i run: `/plesk/parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386' in the terminal nothing happens?

Clearly I have no idea how this should be installed... But this was my best guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must allow the file to be executed:

```
chmod +x parallels_installer_v3.12.0_build120601.16_os_Ubuntu_10.04_i386
```

Then you can run the installer.

Comment: Cheers very much. On the off shot,m you wouldn't happy to know why I might be getting 500 errors when plesk auto installer is trying to download files required for install?

Comment: I have not tried to install it myself, so I don't know what errors are those. Does the program work? If so I would just ignore. If not then I can help you google it... Regards.